# How does lattice determine signal type?

Tags: lattice

I am using Lattice Diamond, I wonder how does lattice recognize the type of
signal when synthesizing vhdl/verilog.

I have a module such :

```
entity test is
PORT ( -- clk  : in std_logic;
      --rst    : in std_logic;
        bclk   : in std_logic; -- burst clock
        da     : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        cs0_n  : in std_logic; -- chipselect 0
        cs1_n  : in std_logic; -- chipselect 1
        lba_n  : in std_logic; -- address valid
        eb     : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- byte enable
        rw_n   : in std_logic; -- write enable (as seen from eim)
        wait_n : out std_logic; -- wait (burst)
        oe_n   : in std_logic; -- read enable (as seen from eim)
        dout   : out std_logic
      );
end entity test;

architecture behavioral of test is

...snip....
begin

   -- the only time rw_n and lba_n appeared :
   -- rw_n, lba_n recognized as clock, while cs0_n as regular port
   da <= (others => 'Z') when cs0_n = '0' AND lba_n = '1' else data_out;
   data_in <= da when rw_n = '0' AND lba_n = '1' else data_in;

...snip....
end
```

Somehow Lattice synthesize `lba_n` and `rw_n` as "Clock Input" in spreadsheet view. Those are not clocks, it should be defined as regular input ports.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a second file, a Logical Preference File (*.lpf). Within this file such constrains are set

> **Understanding Preferences (LPF)**
>
> The LPF contains all the design
> constraints, including timing preferences that you specify for driving
> MAP and PAR using Diamond’s preference language. Although you can add
> or modify preferences before MAP, after MAP, or after PAR, the
> after-MAP or after-PAR changes effectively reset the flow, and changes
> must be implemented by rerunning the MAP and PAR processes Design
> constraints can also be set by using attributes and directives in the
> HDL code. As explained previously, they are converted to EDIF
> properties by logic synthesis, and then carried over into the NGD
> database. They can then be viewed in Spreadsheet View or Package View.
> If the constraints are modified in these views, they will be included
> in the LPF, and these modified preferences will take precedence over
> the attributes in the HDL

[http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/1D/design_planning_document.pdf?document_id=45589](http://www.latticesemi.com/%7E/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/1D/design_planning_document.pdf?document_id=45589)