# How to change the pin type in Lattice Radiant

Tags: lattice

I'm using IP-core with slave-device clock in Lattice Radiant. On the Device Constraint Editor this pin determinated as clock-pin and I can't place it on correct pin on FMC.

This question is similar to [How does lattice determine signal type?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285170/how-does-lattice-determine-signal-type) but I use Lattice Radiant

Comment: Did you search the TCE? (timing constraint editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I'm catching this error:

```
ERROR - par: ldc_set_location of clock driver 'rx_clk' at an illegal pin 'W13'. Unable to reach a CIB entry point for general route clock rx_clk_c in the minimum required distance of 1 PLC.
Please check if the pin is a legal clock pin by
1) Opening 'Tools->Device Constraint Editor' on the top
2) Choosing 'Pin Assgnments' tab in the middle
3) Checking 'Dual Function' column (PCLK*, GR*, etc.) for the pin
```

I'm solve this problem by edit: Project -> Active Strategy -> Place and Route Design -> Command Line Options add: "-exp WARNING_ON_PCLKPLC1=1".

I hope it will be useful to someone.